# Writing a text in a QPixmap

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

I'm having what is follow:

```
QLabel* label_PM= new QLabel(this);
QPixmap PM ("C:/PM.jpg");
label_PM->setPixmap(PM);
```

I would like to insert to the PM a text like what is done in OpenCV cv::putText.

Nothing from research seems to resolve my problem,

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Drawing to a `QPixmap` is done through a `QPainter`.  For example:

```
QPixmap pix = ...;
QPainter painter( &pix );
painter.setFont( QFont("Arial") );
painter.drawText( QPoint(100, 100), "Hello" );
```

This is a very basic usage, look at the `QPainter` documentation for more information.